# Kubernetes Master Node label

Tags: kubernetes

When I was labeling my worker nodes I accidentally labeled my master node as a worker.

**kubectl label node node01 node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker**

now my cluster looks like this:

```
NAME     STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
node01   Ready    master,worker   54m   v1.18.0
node02   Ready    worker          52m   v1.18.0
node03   Ready    worker          51m   v1.18.0
node04   Ready    worker          51m   v1.18.0
```

How do I remove worker from my Master node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kubectl label node node01 node-role.kubernetes.io/worker-`. The `-` tells it to remove the label.